# Passing parameters in Teradata stored procedure (with Looping)

Tags: sql, loops, stored-procedures, teradata

I am from reporting background and first time building cubes from Teradata. I am trying to fill my fact table by one master SP. Master SP will call child SP.
Child SP will be like this- GetData(201704). I have to call this SP for last 13 month(configurable). I have created a table for getting months with rownum which will give me below result.

Month   RowNum

201704  1

201703  2

201702  3

Please find logic for master SP below. If someone can help me with syntax.

CREATE MasterSP(MonthCount)

Begin

Declare Count integer;

Declare Period integer;

SET Count=MonthCount; --13 months

loopstart
IF(I<13)

SELECT Month From TimePeriod WHERE RowNum=Count

SET
GetData(Month)

Count=Count+1

loop end

END

Comment: The syntax for creating a procedure is: `CREATE PROCEDURE [databasename.]procedurename`. Parameters are given as ` [ IN ] | OUT | INOUT } param-name data-type`. Loop is `LOOP ... END LOOP;` If is `IF .... THEN .... END IF;` Set is `SET target = source;` You did declare Period but not use it. You did not declare  `I`. And END needs a closing `;`.  The `SET GetData(Month)` should probably be a `CALL GetData(Month)`. If you use a reserved word `Count` as a variable name you have to enclose it in double quotes.

Comment: Did you check the sql-statement `group by rollup` or `group by cube` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create below SP and working fine.

```
Replace PROCEDURE MYDB.MasterLoad( MntCnt Integer)
BEGIN
Declare MonthCount integer;
Declare IniCount integer;
Declare PeriodNum Integer;

SET IniCount =1;
SET MonthCount = MntCnt;


WHILE IniCount <= MonthCount DO
   BEGIN 

SELECT AccountingReportMonthPeriodNum into PeriodNum  FROM MYDB.Monthly_Dim_TimePeriod WHERE Rownum=IniCount; 

CAll MYDB.MthCustFact_Test(PeriodNum) ;   


SET IniCount = IniCount+1;

   END;
END WHILE;



END;
```